# Hot to reset an Image cropper without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an Image Cropping code that I got online. And it does the job.

Select an image, Can crop it as I like. But the catch is, I m unable to figure out how to reset the script without refreshing the whole page.

Resetting in the sense, remove the selected image or cropping under process image and able to select a new image.

**Here's the Cropping code:**

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropper/2.3.0/cropper.min.css'>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropper/2.3.0/cropper.js'></script>

<input type="file" form="feed-post" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" id="image" onchange="previewFile()" name="image" class="file_image"/>
<div class="img-container" id="some">
  <img id="image_cropped_preview" />
</div>
<a class="salvar post-btn" id="image_crop_btn" >Crop the Image</a>

<script>
var recorte = $('.img-container > img');
recorte.cropper({
  movable: false,
  zoomable: false,
  rotatable: false,
  scalable: false
});

function previewFile() {
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function () {
   $('img').show(); 
   recorte.cropper('replace',reader.result);
  }
  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
   recorte.cropper('replace','');
  }
}

$('.salvar').click(function(){
        temp = recorte.cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toDataURL(); 
        $("#some").html('<iframe src="' + temp  + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>')
});
</script>
```

So, here is the stuff I tried to reset this.

```
<script>
$(".cancel-post").click(function(){
     $("#image_cropped_preview").val('');
     $(".img-container").html('<img id="image_cropped_preview" />');
});
</script>
```

JSFiddle: [Here's the Link](https://jsfiddle.net/harish3693/o7be8vg1/2/)

Unfortunately, the HTML seems to be reset back, but on select, a new image doesn't preview it as earlier until I refresh the whole page.

Any Help is Appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example This example does not include any of the Libraries being used.

Comment: Jquery and cropper libraries updated. Thanks @Twisty

Comment: Does this help: https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs#reset

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function makeCrop(target) {
    console.log("Make Crop Executed");
    return $(target).cropper({
      movable: false,
      zoomable: false,
      rotatable: false,
      scalable: false
    });
  }

  function previewFile() {
    var file = $(this)[0].files[0];
    console.log("Preview File", file.name);
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function() {
      recorte.cropper('replace', reader.result);
      console.log("Reader Loaded");
    }

    if (file) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      console.log("File URL Loaded");
    } else {
      recorte.cropper('replace', '');
    }
    $(".img-title").html(file.name);
    $(".img-input").addClass("hidden");
    $(".img-container, .controls").removeClass("hidden");
  }

  var recorte = makeCrop('.img-container > img');

  $("#image").change(previewFile);

  $('.salvar').click(function() {
    var temp = recorte.cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toDataURL();
    //$("#preview-image").html('<iframe src="' + temp + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>')
  });

  $("#image_reset_btn").click(function() {
    console.log("Reset Image Crop");
    recorte.cropper("reset");
  });

  $("#image_restart_btn").click(function() {
    console.log("Restart Crop from Scratch");
    recorte.cropper('replace', '');
    recorte.cropper("destroy");
    $(".img-input > form")[0].reset();
    $(".img-input input").val("");
    $(".img-input").removeClass("hidden");
    $(".img-container, .controls").addClass("hidden");
    $(".img-container img").removeAttr("src");
    recorte = makeCrop('.img-container > img');
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropper/2.3.0/cropper.min.css'>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropper/2.3.0/cropper.js'></script>
<div class="img-input">
  <form>
    <input type="file" form="feed-post" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" id="image" name="image" class="file_image" />
  </form>
</div>
<div class="img-container hidden" id="preview-image">
  <div class="img-title"></div>
  <img id="image_cropped_preview" />
</div>
<div class="controls hidden">
  <button class="salvar post-btn" id="image_crop_btn">Crop the Image</button>
  <button class="reset-btn" id="image_reset_btn">Reset Crop</button>
  <button class="reset-btn" id="image_restart_btn">Start Over</button>
</div>
```

If the User selects to "Start Over" it destroys the Cropper, resets everything, and re-initializes Cropper. There may be a better way to do it all yet this got it working as one might expect.

Reference: https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper

Comment: Hey @Twisty Thanks a lot for the reply, I really appreciate it. Although it works perfectly fine. I wish I can correct my code and use it as I have a good understanding of it and used it in a lot of places.  

Here's a JSFiddle of it for you : https://jsfiddle.net/harish3693/o7be8vg1/2/